# Label x and y axis values in plot with matrix cols and rows names

Tags: r

I have the following matrix and then I paint it according to intervals as shown below

```
mdat <- matrix(c(0.25,0.45,0.3, 0.75,0.15,0.62,0.40,0.90,1, 0.45,0.15,0), nrow = 4, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE) 



plot(rep(1:4, 3), mdat, pch=15, cex=2.5,
                   col=c("red","orange","blue", "green")[findInterval(mdat, c(0,.25,.5,.75, 1.1))])
```

And it works fine as shown in the image.

But now if I define

```
dimnames(mdat) <- list(  c("row1", "row2", "row3","row4"), c("col1", "col2", "col3"))
```

I need to change in the plot the values in x axis and in the y axis to be row1..row4 instead of the values 0.0.. 1.0  and col1.. col3 instead of 1.0.. 4.0 [image]

Comment: See [QuickR](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html) Axes section.  Should completely answer your question.

Comment: I tried defining b<-names(mdat[,2]) and axis(1,1:4,b) but can't find how to replace the old labels in the x axis with this new values, now I have both of them

Comment: "If you are going to create a custom axis, you should suppress the axis automatically generated by your high level plotting function. The option axes=FALSE suppresses both x and y axes. xaxt="n" and yaxt="n" suppress the x and y axis respectively." [QuickR](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html)

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't notice before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered doing this with ggplot? just a suggestion...

```
library(ggplot2)
mdat <- data.frame(Y = c(0.25,0.45,0.3, 0.75,0.15,0.62,0.40,0.90,1, 0.45,0.15,0),
                   X = factor(c(rep("row1",3), rep("row2",3), rep("row3",3), rep("row4",3))))
mdat$Z <- factor(findInterval(mdat$Y, c(0,.25,.5,.75, 1.1)))
P <- ggplot(mdat, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point(aes(colour = Z), size = 11)
P + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I should take a look at ggplot